# How to display html data in my app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using Angular framework to populate my data in my app.

my data contains html tag

It's something like

```
$scope.test = <p>this is a test<?p><strong>Bold text here...</strong>
```

In my html

```
<div>
   {{test}}
</div>
```

The output on browser show exact text '`<p>this is a test</p> <strong>Bold text here...</strong>`'. I want it to parse html tag and show'

this is a test

**Bold text here...**.

Is that possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can either do:

```
<div ng-bing-html-unsafe="test"></div>
```

or

```
$scope.test = $sce.trustAsHtml('<p>this is a test<?p><strong>Bold text here...</strong>');
```

Depending on what you need to do and what version of angular you are using.  Just saw you said 1.2, so most likely the last one.  And for the $sce one you obviously need to inject $sce:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
   $scope.test = $sce.trustAsHtml('<p>this is a test<?p><strong>Bold text here...</strong>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make directive for parsing text to html content.
like

```
app.directive('bindUnsafeHtml', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("in directive");
          scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
              // watch the 'bindUnsafeHtml' expression for changes
              return scope.$eval(attrs.bindUnsafeHtml);
            },
            function(value) {
              // when the 'bindUnsafeHtml' expression changes
              // assign it into the current DOM
              element.html(value);

              // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
              // scope.
              // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
              // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
    };
}]);
```

After that you can use like:

```
 <div bind-unsafe-html="test">
```

**Don't forgot to inject your directive in the config of angular**

Hope this will help you.